# JS Form Validation: adding a red border on input fields with errors; removing it on focus?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to set up some form validation for my website. What I want to achieve is:

When JS detects an empty field, it puts a red border around it; and later, when the user focuses (puts the cursor in the input field) the border is removed and does not return. I tried doing it with CSS because it may have been a shorter way, however the red border returns once the user removes the input field out of focus.

It seems like the problem is with the function parameter. Is JS unable to use the parameter (`fieldName`) if it is in the middle of a method? (`document.contactForm.`**`fieldName`**`.style.border="none !important";`)

Here is a link to an illustration of my problem on **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sonbrL2r/

The first function is called upon form submission. If it detects an empty form it puts a red border around the text field;

The second function is then meant to remove said border upon focus of that text field.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <form name="contactForm" onSubmit="return formValidate();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Your Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="realname" size="44" maxlength="60" onFocus="removeBorder(realname);"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="SEND" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var formValidate = function() {
    var formValid = true;
    var errorMsg = "Oops! Looks like you didn't complete the form properly: \n";

        if (document.contactForm.realname.value == "") {
            document.contactForm.realname.style.border="2px solid #cc3333";
            errorMsg+="The name field is empty.\n";
            var formValid = false;

    if(!formValid) {alert(errorMsg)};   
    return formValid;
};

var removeBorder = function(fieldName) {
    document.contactForm.fieldName.style.border="none !important";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me but, since the `fieldName` is a variable so this:

```
document.contactForm.fieldName.style.border
```

Should be written like this:

```
document.contactForm[fieldName].style.border
```

Comment: This gives a syntax error and renders the whole .js file non-functional.

Comment: Thank you for help. No syntax error this time, but the function still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Sorry! Like I said, it's not clear to me how you've called the `removeBorder` function using which event and how did you code it, so can't tell more.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like stackoverflow occasionally cuts out bits of code. I added a jsfiddle link, maybe that way it will be clearer? I call the `removeBorder` function by using `onFocus` inside the `input` tag; as the function parameter I pass on the `name` attribute of said input.